# How to use Azure Key Vault in android

Tags: android, azure, azure-blob-storage, azure-keyvault

I'm using Azure as cloud storage, i'm able to upload and download the images/files in Azure blob container using following link.

[Azure Blob storage](https://github.com/uglide/azure-content/blob/master/articles/storage/storage-java-how-to-use-blob-storage.md)

Now to provide security we are planing to use key vault. Using key vault keys need to access the blob storage in azure.
There is no information available for android to use key vault. If anyone knows anything please post it.If i miss anything to mention please comment i will update it. I'm new to azure implementation.

**Edit:-** My goal is to display images in app which are stored in Azure blob storage.Instead of accessing azure storage directly by using Key vault i want to access it. After getting secrete key from key vault how to connect azure with that key ?

Comment: what exactly do you want to use KeyVault for? Storage encryption with BYOK? Retrieving storage keys from KeyVault? etc..

Comment: @silent i want to get keys from keyvault to access my azure blob storage from my android application.

Comment: Did you want to store storage connectionstring in azure keyvault secret?

Comment: do not use the (main) storage key for your scenario! If anything, use SAS tokens with a certain expiry time.

Comment: @JoeyCai keys are stored in key vault i want access them and use them to access blob storage.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> keys are stored in key vault i want access them and use them to access blob storage

**Don't use Azure Keyvault when you're building a mobile app.** At least not directly.

You see, we want to keep all app secrets off the device if possible. Even if they're never being stored and will only be in memory transiently.

To solve this particular conumdrum, we're still going to take advantage of Keyvault and all it has to offer and put the Azure Storage API key in there.

But instead of having the mobile app directly access the Table storage, we're going to have an `Azure Function` do that.

For more details, you could refer to this [article](https://codemilltech.com/mobile-apps-azure-keyvault-dont-do-it/).

Comment: TQ, above mentioned article give me clear idea, even after using functional app we will get the secrets.Then how to connect blob storage using those secret keys.

Comment: still i didn't get full answer if i'm unable to find then i will accept ur answer.

Comment: All right. If you still have any problem, please feel free to let me know.

Comment: The app here is specified as android app?

Comment: As the article I provided, you could not use keyvault in app directly.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/193630/discussion-between-ybdevi-and-joey-cai).

Comment: As per that article i will use functional app and get the keys.
I want to know how to use those keys to access azure blob storage from android app

Comment: Here is the [article](http://liliankasem.com/2016/02/29/how-to-use-azure-blob-storage-on-android/) you could refer to.

Comment: i have already implemented that and it is working fine if we are using real strings(Storage name,Connection string).Instead of them if if we use the secretes it is not working and exception is coming like 'Invalid connection string'.

Comment: I have achieved it fallowing ur answer and this link(https://www.programcreek.com/java-api-examples/?code=jgroups-extras/jgroups-azure/jgroups-azure-master/azure/src/main/java/org/jgroups/protocols/azure/AZURE_PING.java) as  reference.

Comment: But then, aren't we making function access public? That way anyone could get secret by hitting the azure function.

Comment: As @AnuragShukla points out - how is the better security when you create an Azure Funtion that is publicly accessible?

Answer (score 0):

A small bit of anatomy, in case you're not very familiar with azure cloud: we have **Azure Function** -> block of executable code, triggered by a http request or other (e.g. database triggers) and **Azure Function App** which is an umbrella for having multiple functions.

1. **Azure Functions** have different levels of security: anonymous, function and host keys https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/security-concepts?tabs=v4
2. By creating an **Azure Function App**, you can secure the function **app** itself with the OAuth2 protocol https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/overview-authentication-authorization

if you're using other cloud providers, like gcp you can also authenticate with a federated token, see https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/workload-identity-federation-create-trust-gcp?tabs=azure-cli%2Ctypescript

Because you created this authentication flow, even if your function doesn't have a key (your function security is **anonymous**), the function app (which you need to authenticate to with OAuth2 flow) can now call the unprotected function URI.

One more note, to actually grasp this, try creating a FunctionApp yourself, where you disable authentification, and if you access the link, you'll see no credentials requirement and check if by copying your AzureFunction uri that you can call the function (anonymous level security).

Now add authentification on FunctionApp and see for yourself that you can no longer call the AzureFunction.

To sum up https://codemilltech.com/mobile-apps-azure-keyvault-dont-do-it/

Now you no longer have to manage secrets, or api codes in your app. All your api's codes and secret now reside where they should - your backend.

Sorry for the wrong answer, I know it might be a bit redundant but this is how I understood the entire access of an **Azure Resource(keyvault)** through an **Azure function** which is under the umbrella of **Function App**, which counterintuitively has the security level to anonymous.